# regex how would i search for asterisk-space-equals sign?

Tags: php, regex

what regex would be used to search for an asterisk followed by a space followed by an equlas sign?

that is `'* ='` ?

Using preg_match in php would find a match in these strings:

```
'yet again * = it happens'

'again* =it happens'
```

and what is simplest way to search for an exact word for word, number for number, puncuation sign for puncuation sign string in regex?

Comment: Why bother with a regular expression for this? What's wrong with strpos?

Comment: Can you explain the second part of your question in more detail, or may be show some input and expected output?

Comment: you know, i googled for php function like preg_match no regex and i couldnt really find anything.  Yep, strpos looks like the way to go

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a regular expression here. Consider using [`strpos`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php)

```
$pos = strpos('yet again * = it happens', '* =');
if(pos === false){
    // not there
}
else {
    // found
}
```

If you must use `preg_match`, remember the delimiters:

```
preg_match('/\* =/', $str, $matches);
```

In this case you have to escape the asterisk. You may want to allow more spaces, for example with the pattern `\*\h+=`. `\h` stands for [horizontal whitespace characters](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.escape.php).

Comment: why doesnt the equals sign have a back slash in front of it?

Comment: @SlickRick - It isn't a regex meta-character. It isn't special, so you don't have to escape it - if you want to match `'Rick'`, you wouldn't write `'\R\i\c\k'`, would you? `:)`

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex pattern

```
\*(?=\s=)
```

Comment: preg_match("\*(?=\s=)", $string) isn't working. warning:  Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash

Comment: You have to escape characters that have special meaning in strings (like `\`)

Comment: do you actually use the word like?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
function runme($txt) {  
    return preg_match("/^\*\ \=$/", $txt);
}
echo runme($argv[1])? "$argv[1] matches!\n" : "$argv[1] is not asterisk space equals-sign\n";
?>

$ php asterisk_space_equals.php 'yet again * = it happens'
yet again * = it happens is not asterisk space equals-sign

$ php asterisk_space_equals.php 'again* =it happens'
again* =it happens is not asterisk space equals-sign

$ php asterisk_space_equals.php '* ='
* = matches!
```

Comment: This just checks for the *exact string* `* =` - not quite what the OP asked for, and it can be done with simple string comparison.